# Move and upgrade mediawiki without upgrade first

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki version 1.21.2 (php 5.3.10, mysql 5.5.35, Apache/2.2.22, Ubuntu 12.04.4) and I want to move it to a new server with mediawiki version 1.29.1 (php 7.0.22, mysql 5.7.19, Apache/2.4.18, Ubuntu 16.04.3).

The old site is configured as a wiki-family with 5 associated wikis.

It seems the normal approach is to first upgrade the source site and then move the upgraded site to the target server.

The old site must remain active (read only) and as-is and will be turned off after the new site is in place.

I would like to try an approach with the following steps:

1. install version 1.29.1 on the target server
2. sql dump the datafiles from the source server
3. import the sql dump files into the target server database
4. run some update scripts to bring the source files into compliance with the target database

Of course I'll need to manage the media and extensions.

The target server already has php 7.0.22, mysql 5.7.19 (installed as part of default LAMP), so I suspect I'll have to downgrade components only to re-upgrade them. Maybe not.

Can anyone suggest the cleanest way to do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the old server prior to moving the wiki is not really necessary.

You can follow your own steps:

1. Download your new MediaWiki version on the new server
2. Download/copy any additional extensions you need on the new server. Try to download new copies of extensions that match your MediaWiki version instead of copying them from the old server, since they may be incompatible with the new MediaWiki version
3. Copy your old media to the new server
4. Copy your LocalSettings.php from the old server to the new one and adapt it: you may need to change some settings or disable incompatible extensions.
5. Dump your database from the old server, and import it on the new server.
6. [Run the update script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading).

You can do that even with the old wiki running, to test if the upgrade will work, and then redo it again putting the old wiki in read-only mode during the move.

Comment: Thank you.  Very clean and concise.